# Как создать массив указателей на функции-члены разных классов?

Tags: массивы, классы, указатели, c++

Существует несколько классов, наследованных от базового класса. Как создать массив указателей на функции-члены этих классов? Функции-члены имеют разные типы принимаемых параметров и разные типы возвращаемых значений.

Хочется сделать так: пользователь вводит с клавиатуры номер ячейки массива, в которой содержится функция, и она выполяется над объектом.

Comment: А откуда берутся аргументы для вызова? Что должно произойти с возвращаемым значением? Как определяется, какая именно из функций-членов вызывается для данного объекта?

Comment: Аргументы для вызова: после выбора номера ячейки массива, в которой содержится указатель на функцию, пользователь в функцию передает требуемые ей аргументы, вводимые с клавиатуры, либо не передает вообще, если в сигнатуре функции их нет.
Возвращаемое значение: сохраняется в переменной, потом выводится на экран.
Указатели на конкретные функции объекта содержатся в массиве, пользователь помнит, в какой ячейке массива какая функция находится, либо ему на экран выводится подсказка.

Comment: А над каким объектом выполняется функция?

Comment: Пожалуй, основной вопрос, котороый стоит тут задать, - _зачем_? Опишите ситуацию, в которой возникает необходимость в подобных конструкциях, возможно, есть более простой путь.

Comment: Извините, согласен, на вопрос легче ответить когда есть конкретный пример. Итак, классика учебного жанра, CStudent::public CPerson, CWorker::public CPerson. В каждом классе, есть виртуальные методы, типа 'float SpendMoney(float money);' и обычные, не виртуальные, типа CStudent.ReceiveScholarship() и CWorker.ReceiveWage(float). Требуется организовать диалог с пользователем в стиле командной строки, который будет с помощью методов оперировать объектами этих классов. Хочется избежать конструкции switch, и передавать сразу номер ячейки, в которой находится нужная нам функция.
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Роман Одесса

- Попробуйте абстрагироваться от ячеек и прочей лабуды, а опишите лучше, как должен происходить диалог. Пользователь не знает и не должен знать про ваши `CStudent`, `CWorker` и уж тем более про виртуальность их методов.

- Вот человек открывает ваше приложение. Что он видит перед собой? Что ему нужно сделать? Что он должен получить?

Comment: Открыв приложение, юзер получает текстовое меню, в котором всего два выбора (1-создать объект CStudent,2-создать объект CWorker). После выбора, юзер вводит данные для инициализации полей объекта по умолчанию (год роджения, фио, прочее). Далее снова получает текстовое меню (1-ПолучитьСтипендию, 2-ПотратитьДеньги, 3-ПоступитьВВуз, и т.п.). Я хочу, чтобы пункты выбора(1,2,3) были не case'ами (case 1:, case 2:, case 3), а номерами ячеек массива, в которых будут лежать указатели на методы. Как-то так.

Comment: При выборе пункта должна не просто выполниться функция с N аргументами: аргументы должны быть введены пользователем, преобразованы в нужные типы, скормлены функции, получен результат, результирующий объект переведён в представление, понятное пользователю, и показан. Всё это оформите в одну функцию без параметров и возвращаемого значения (возможно, лямбду). Теперь в каждой ячейке массива будет просто `std::function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, можно объявить тип функции `typedef (void* myfunc)(void*);`, создать из них массив, передавать в функции указатели на параметры, а внутри функций кастовать параметры в нужный тип. Можно даже сделать так, чтобы функции могли принимать различное число аргументов (через varargs). Вот только уж больно это противоестественно выглядит. И ещё, вы говорите, что функции должны возвращать значения, причём разных типов. Как вы собираетесь это обрабатывать? Тут вам в любом случае понадобится `switch`. Так почему бы не сделать его сразу? Да и со входными параметрами проблема: их нужно не просто прочитать из консоли, но и отнести к определённому типу. Иначе каст внутри функции вернёт какую-нибудь чепуху. Короче, мой вам совет: пишите `switch`, а вышеописанные извращения оставьте для языков, в которых реализована рефлексия.